# How to save checkout data in localStorage and remove it when order complete use React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am use this function to store `localStorage` data

```
const useLocalStorage = (key, defaultValue) => {
    const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
    const initial = stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : defaultValue;
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [key, value]);

    return [value, setValue];
};
```

and show data

```
const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage('checkoutItem', checkoutItems);
```

But it seems like it is save in  `localStorage` but when page reload it show `localStorage is not defined` . i want to save checkout data and remove it when order complete.

Comment: localStorage is not defined might mean that your code is running on the server initially where window object is not available and localStorage is a browser API. This hook should be running only in the browser. With that said you might be using server-side-rendering ? Next. JS here ?

Comment: yes i am using next js